# Visual Studio - TypeScript project only

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, project, visual-studio-extensions

I am currently working on some frontend typescript projects. In Visual Studio, there are only two options which project to chose for this purpose: HTML Application with TypeScript (this is which I am currently using) and VS Extensions for Node.js (which is not ideal for frontend app development).

The first option works fine, including debugging of JS files but it includes also C# code for backend and IIS modules which I don't need at all in case of frontend project. Build of C# slows down build of solution dramatically especially in case when there are multiple projects in the solution.

I have 3 questions related to this:

- a) did anybody of you see any VS extension allowing development and
  debugging of pure TypeScript projects with possibility of debugging
  in the IIS Express (and ideally also with Chrome Debugging Protocol
  which is also supported by Edge?

  b) If not, because I have no experience with extensions development
  and MSBUILD, at all. How difficult would it be to write such
  extension and what I would need for it?

  c) Would be somebody so kind and help me with development of such
  extension? :)

I am talking about VS2015. It should be also possible to use it in VS2017.

Answer (score 0):

With the release of TypeScript 0.8.1, which supports debugging using the source map format in visual studio.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2012/11/15/announcing-typescript-0-8-1/

> TypeScript now supports source level debugging!  The source map format has been gaining popularity as a way of debugging languages which translate to JavaScript and is supported by a variety of browsers and tools.  With version 0.8.1, the TypeScript compiler officially supports source maps.  Additionally, the new version of TypeScript for Visual Studio 2012 supports debugging using the source map format.

In addition, you could also debug Typescript in Visual Studio Code
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jtarquino/2016/01/24/debugging-typescript-in-visual-studio-code-and-chrome/
https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2016/02/23/introducing-chrome-debugger-for-vs-code